# I cant solve an equation for a variable. Please help

Tags: equation-solving

[image: Iam expecting this end result]

I was expecting the software to solve for `2\[Nu]`. But it gives some complicated results. It's easy to solve by hand.

```
'f1 = 4 \[Beta]11 \[Beta]22 \[Omega]01 \[Omega]02 (1 + (4 (2 \[Nu] - \[Omega]01 - \[Omega]02)^2/(\[Beta]11 + \[Beta]22)^2)) - \[Lambda]12 \[Lambda]21

Solve[f1 == 0, \[Nu]] // Simplify'
```

[image: Snap shot of my code]

Comment: Try `Solve[f1 == 0, \[Nu], Reals] // Simplify`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
f1 = 4 \[Beta]11 \[Beta]22 \[Omega]01 \[Omega]02 (1 + (4 (2 \[Nu] - \
\[Omega]01 - \[Omega]02)^2/(\[Beta]11 + \[Beta]22)^2)) - \[Lambda]12 \
\[Lambda]21;

sol = Solve[f1 == 0, \[Nu]] // 
  Simplify[#, {\[Beta]11, \[Beta]22, \[Omega]01, \[Omega]02, \
\[Lambda]12, \[Lambda]21} \[Element] Reals] &


(*  {{\[Nu] -> 
   1/8 (4 (\[Omega]01 + \[Omega]02) + ((\[Beta]11 + \[Beta]22)^2 (-\
\[Lambda]12 \[Lambda]21 + 
         4 \[Beta]11 \[Beta]22 \[Omega]01 \[Omega]02))/(
      Sqrt[-\[Beta]11 \[Beta]22 \[Omega]01 \[Omega]02 (-\[Lambda]12 \
\[Lambda]21 + 4 \[Beta]11 \[Beta]22 \[Omega]01 \[Omega]02)]
        Abs[\[Beta]11 + \[Beta]22]))}, {\[Nu] -> 
   1/8 (4 (\[Omega]01 + \[Omega]02) - ((\[Beta]11 + \[Beta]22)^2 (-\
\[Lambda]12 \[Lambda]21 + 
         4 \[Beta]11 \[Beta]22 \[Omega]01 \[Omega]02))/(
      Sqrt[-\[Beta]11 \[Beta]22 \[Omega]01 \[Omega]02 (-\[Lambda]12 \
\[Lambda]21 + 4 \[Beta]11 \[Beta]22 \[Omega]01 \[Omega]02)]
        Abs[\[Beta]11 + \[Beta]22]))}}  *)
```

This is your solution. You can simplify it. There can be several approaches. One selects the approach that gives him the expression that he believes to be best from his point of view. I would do the following:

```
((sol /. a_^2 -> Abs[a]*Hold[Abs[a]] // 
      ReleaseHold) /. \[Lambda]12 -> (-x + 
      4 \[Beta]11 \[Beta]22 \[Omega]01 \[Omega]02)/\[Lambda]21) /. (
   x*a_)/Sqrt[x*b_] -> (Sqrt[x]*a)/Sqrt[b] /. 
 x -> (-\[Lambda]12 \[Lambda]21 + 
    4 \[Beta]11 \[Beta]22 \[Omega]01 \[Omega]02)

(* {{\[Nu] -> 
   1/8 (4 (\[Omega]01 + \[Omega]02) + (
      Sqrt[-\[Lambda]12 \[Lambda]21 + 
        4 \[Beta]11 \[Beta]22 \[Omega]01 \[Omega]02]
        Abs[\[Beta]11 + \[Beta]22])/
      Sqrt[-\[Beta]11 \[Beta]22 \[Omega]01 \[Omega]02])}, {\[Nu] -> 
   1/8 (4 (\[Omega]01 + \[Omega]02) - (
      Sqrt[-\[Lambda]12 \[Lambda]21 + 
        4 \[Beta]11 \[Beta]22 \[Omega]01 \[Omega]02]
        Abs[\[Beta]11 + \[Beta]22])/
      Sqrt[-\[Beta]11 \[Beta]22 \[Omega]01 \[Omega]02])}}  *)
```

To make the result better visible, below I show its picture:

[image]

It seems to be close to what you want.

Have fun!

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Why was this down-voted? (I gave a vote to even the score)

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I gave a vote because I am not sure what's happening with downvoting right answers these days. And questions that are fine to be honest. And because other than a mere "thank you" it should have been accepted

Comment: @bmf I saw you had done that recently. I also am baffled by the recent downvotes. As for accepting, the poster is new and maybe even unfamiliar with the process. Did say thank you so that’s a good sign. Also…maybe someone accidentally hit the wrong arrow? I’ve done that at least once. Which doesn’t explain the recent spate.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I guess you are right and I perhaps I was a bit to harsch with the poster in this case. And I can see how one would mis-click the downvote accidentally, but it seems that it's getting out of hand these past days. Anyway, let's hope for the best!